# How to get azure function URL at runtime C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to get azure function URL (at runtime) for Http triggered function app developed in C#.I have implemented a health check for function app.I need to call function URL to check whether the function is healthy or not . I know azure provide services to check FA health but I need to implement as per organization standards. So, Basically it will be a endpoint /healthCheck to get health report.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? some code you have so far could be helpful to understand the question.

Comment: Would you kindly share you code so that we could better visualize your issue.

Comment: I have implemented a health check for function app.I need to call function URL to check whether the function is healthy or not . I know azure provide services to check FA health but I need to implement as per organization standards.
So, Basically it will be a endpoint /healthCheck to get health report.

Comment: so basically your Function will call itself to do a health check on itself?!

Comment: Does the below answer helps your query?

Answer (score 1):

While I don't understand yet what you are trying to do (and if that is a good idea..) you can infer your function URL through the [pre-set env var](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment) WEBSITE_HOSTNAME (assuming you are not using a custom domain):

```
var url = $"https://{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME")}/api/YOURFUNCTIONNAME";
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a need of getting runtime Azure function app URLs as they remain the same always after creation. On the same lines, you can automate your Function Apps using [ARM templates](https://harshi-singh94.medium.com/a-quick-guide-on-writing-your-azure-resource-manager-arm-templates-8e803c91655b).

And, use the created URLs defined in your endpoint's configuration and use them in your code from the configuration. *For example, if you are using App Service, you can save those values in App Settings and read them like below:*

```
var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("your_key_here");
```

Comment: Yes , I can set function URL in app settings of function app using ARM template . But, for first time when the FA is provisioned , there wont be any function deployed in FA. As per my understanding, I need an separate task (post function deployment) in devops pipeline to set function URL in FA settings.